# Generate table with sequential times using PHP

Tags: php, time, html-table

I am trying to write a site that generates a schedule.  The left hand column of the table should display times starting at 7:00 am and increase by 30 minutes with each row.  I'm not sure how to increase the time by 30 minutes.  I can only display the current time:

CODE:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>Friday</td>
</tr>
<?php
    $p=0;
    $r=7;
    while($p<30){
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo date('g:i a');
        echo "</td></tr>";
        $p++;

    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: @matt i just googled that and not only did i not get a helpful answer, I did not know how to formulate that search at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function has an optional second parameter for a timestamp.

If you know the time of 7am for a given day (using something like [mktime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)), then you can add increments of 30 minutes to it.  Because timestamps are in seconds, you'd be adding `(60 * 30)` for each increment.